# EWOULDBLOCK Error in socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

I use socket in non-blocking mode, Client send data continuously to Server, although I set buffer for socket is big enough to save all data from client but Ewouldblock always threw, I don't know why, could you explain to me in detail about this Ewouldblock.

Comment: Ewouldblock thew from send() function

Comment: Please edit your question to include some of your actual code

Answer (score 6):

EWOULDBLOCK means that the socket send buffer is full when sending, or that the socket receive buffer is empty when receiving. You are supposed to use `select()` to detect when these conditions become false.

Comment: But i set size buffer is big enough to save all data that i want to send, why still ewouldblock threw from send() function? Except buffer is full.

Comment: @nguyenngoc101 The send buffer can fill if you are writing faster than the reader is reading. You need to think of the network between you and the peer as a fixed size pipe, not as an infinitely expandable balloon. The data has to go somewhere.

Comment: Client just send one packet, tested at localhost. I set buffer size is bigger than capacity of the packet.the packet splits into pieces and send continuously this piesces

Comment: I am referring to the socket buffers controlled by SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF.

Comment: I understood what you mean, but could you show me when Ewouldblock threw from send() function,except buffer is full. Thank you so much.

Comment: @nguyenngoc101 Never. EWOULDBLOCK when sending *means* that the send buffer is full. Nothing else.